# Photon, Disable component on player from another client

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I'm trying to disable a light component from another component on a player.
I've tried a couple of methods, mostly the same.

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
    {
        Debug.Log("light");
        transform.GetComponent<PhotonView>().RPC("EnableFlash", RpcTarget.All, gameObject.name);
    }
}

[PunRPC]
void EnableFlash(string name)
{
    Light light = GetComponent<Light>();
    light.enabled = !light.enabled;
}
```

This is turning my light off, this cannot be seen on other clients for some reason and there are no errors for this piece of code.

Second try:

```
void Update()
{
    // Torch on//off
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
    {
        pv.RPC("LightToggled", RpcTarget.All, gameObject.name, torchActive);
        torchActive = !torchActive;
    }
}

[PunRPC]
public void LightToggled(string name, bool active)
{
    GameObject g = GameObject.Find(name);
    GameObject light = g.GetComponent<PlayerExtras>().torch.gameObject;
    light.SetActive(active);
}
```

This does not work either.

Comment: Are you sure that the names are same on both clients for `GameObject.Find()`?

Comment: @DigvijaysinhGohil I will have to check that, I am pretty sure they would be the same but i would have to check :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @DigvijaysinhGohil said in the comment under my question said I needed to make sure that both clients had the same name.
They did not so to fix this i had to change the name of the player with the script below:

```
void Start()
{
    string name_ = pv.Owner.ToString();
    name_ = name_.Split()[1];
    gameObject.name = name_;
}
```

this script changes it from `#01 'jerry'` to `'jerry'`. this changed on all clients and made sure that they are the same name.

:)